# Why does PrismaORM SessionStore throws error in session declaration?

Tags: typescript, session, nestjs, prisma, express-session

While trying to implement session store using prisma orm in nestjs, I got an error while declaring the session store. Below is my code and the error. I think I did the same thing as described in the official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@quixo3/prisma-session-store), but got an error from "new PrismaClient()"

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as passport from 'passport';
import { PrismaSessionStore } from '@quixo3/prisma-session-store';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.use(
    session({
      name: 'SESSION_ID',
      secret: 'secret from env file!',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000,
      },
      store: new PrismaSessionStore(new PrismaClient(), {
        checkPeriod: 2 * 60 * 1000, //ms
        dbRecordIdIsSessionId: true,
        dbRecordIdFunction: undefined,
      }),
    }),
  );

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

and this is the error I got:

"*error TS2345: Argument of type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPrisma<"session">'.
Property 'session' is missing in type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation>' but required in type 'Record<"session", { create(args: ICreateArgs): Promise; delete(args: IDeleteArgs): Promise; deleteMany(args?: unknown): Promise<...>; findMany(args?: IFindManyArgs): Promise<...>; findUnique(args: IFindUniqueArgs): Promise<...>; update(args: IUpdateArgs): Promise<...>; }>'.*"

BTW, below is some part of my prisma schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Session {
  id        Int      @id(map: "PK_Sessions") @default(autoincrement())
  sid       Int
  data      String   @db.NVarChar(Max)
  expiresAt DateTime
}

//and so on...
```

Not so sure but my understanding is that it expects a "session". What is the point I am missing? I followed the official documentation, searched for similar problems but couldn't find any answer. Any help will be appreciated.